# SharePoint 2010 starting workflows after saving changes to document

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint 2010. I have placed a document into an approval workflow but have not initiated it. Whenever a use makes a change to the document, it is starting the approval workflow.

How do I stop this? I want to manually start the workflows.

Answer (score 3):

This is a setting in your workflow.  You can go into your workflow configuration (in your list settings) and untick 'Changing an item will start this workflow.'

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem you need to change the settings of your approval workflow.
Go to your workflow settings and untick `start workflow automatically when an item is changed` and tick the option named `Allow this workflow to be manually started`.

Here is more about SP 2010 Approval Workflow. May be you will find it helpful :

[Understand approval workflows in SharePoint Server](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-approval-workflows-in-SharePoint-2010-a24bcd14-0e3c-4449-b936-267d6c478579)